# how to make multi CountDown in one page using jquery?

Tags: javascript

I need some help with javascript code, I try to get A code that will work for multi countdown timers at same page. I tried the code below but no success.

```js
$(".expirydiv").each(function(){
        var timer = $(this).attr("data-promo");
    var countDownDate = new Date(timer).getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function() {

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);    

                    $(this).text(days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                $(this).text("EXPIRED");
              }

    }, 1000);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expirydiv" data-promo="2021/12/27 10:59:00"></div>
<div class="expirydiv" data-promo="2021/12/19 05:09:00"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) is scoped inside setInterval, so you need a reference:

```js
$(".expirydiv").each(function() {
  var timer = $(this).attr("data-promo");
  var countDownDate = new Date(timer).getTime();
// HERE I CREATE A REFERENCE TO $(this) THAT IS PASSED TO SetInterval
  var $this = $(this);
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    $this.text(days + "d " + hours + "h " +
      minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      $this.text("EXPIRED");
    }

  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expirydiv" data-promo="2021/12/27 10:59:00"></div>
<div class="expirydiv" data-promo="2021/12/19 05:09:00"></div>
```

Comment: @AndhikaNanda if it works and solved your problem, please accept the answer.